# Multiple input value not able to store in database

Tags: php, html, laravel, variant

I have created an admin panel in Laravel for my hotel booking website with a table in which admins can add values and store it within the database.

Here is how my data base table looks like:
[image]

```
<input type="hidden" v-model="row.id" v-bind:name="'variant[' + key + '][id]'">
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type" v-model="row.type" v-bind:name="'variant[' + key + '][type]'"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Price" v-model="row.price" v-bind:name="'variant[' + key + '][price]'"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Total rooms" v-model="row.no_of_rooms" v-bind:name="'variant[' + key + '][no_of_rooms]'"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Occuppancy" v-model="row.max_occupancy" v-bind:name="'variant[' + key + '][max_occupancy]'"></td>
    <td><textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Description" v-model="row.description" v-bind:name="'variant[' + key + '][description]'"></textarea></td>
    <!-- <td><textarea class="form-control" placeholder="room no's" v-model="row.room_no" v-bind:name="'variant[' + key + '][room_no]'"></textarea></td> -->
    <td> <input-tag :tags.sync="room_no" v-model="row.room_no" v-bind:name="'variant[' + key + '][room_no]'"></input-tag></td>
    <td><a type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" v-on:click="removeRow(key)"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a></td>
</tr>
```

All inputs fields are getting stored in the database except the field below.

```
<td> <input-tag :tags.sync="room_no" v-model="row.room_no" v-bind:name="'variant[' + key + '][room_no]'"></input-tag></td>
```

if i try using below input type i can save the data

When I use the input-tags value it's not getting to the controller and it's showing an error as Undefined index: room_no

Comment: Can you post your sql table ? Maybe it's just a wrong name in html

Comment: and what you tried in php? and also the result of $request->all() from where you receive the data?

Comment: @DessaugesAntoine i have added my table in question

Comment: @Indra if i try using below input type i can save the data
 <td><textarea class="form-control" placeholder="room no's" v-model="row.room_no" v-bind:name="'variant[' + key + '][room_no]'"></textarea></td> 


when i use input-tag value its not getting in controller  and showing error as Undefined index: room_no

Comment: @ZubairNazerOliyat Why is this an `<input-tag>` and not just an `<input>`? Never see this and can't find it on the net. (Look like v-model in a Vue.js thing and I never use it so maybe I'm totally wrong)

Comment: @ZubairNazerOliyat you should add the vue.js tag. Also I asked you for the php code and the result of that function. I can't help you as is